# What's the best practice for SPA-PWA authentication?

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, jwt, single-page-application, progressive-web-apps

I'm trying to develop a single page application using web APIs in ASP.NET Core as backend, and React as Frontend.
I was wondering what's the best practice to handle authentication using SPA-PWA technologies, i'd like to use 3rd party authentication so the user won't need to create another account.

Comment: I was aiming for OAuth2.0 with Google, Facebook et al and the Credential Management API but doesn't look like Microsoft or Apple will ever support it :-( With privacy (no-tracking) becoming more important it looks like WebAuth is the way to go.